# React change state with setTimeOut calling setState again

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

New to react native.
I want to use state to change a button colour (that I defined in a class component) on a certain condition.
I used setTimeOut and setState and right now the button changes, but only once (from darkgreen to lightgreen). Tried using setInterval and it did the same. I want it to change from dark to light and back to dark again. But I can't seem to find a way to call setState again. Would like some help, please. Thanks a lot, here is the class component:

```
class Green extends Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.state={}
         this.state.custum={
            backgroundColor: 'darkgreen'
         }

         if (this.props.greenFlash){
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState( {
                    custum:{
                        backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
                    }
                    })
            }, 1000);
        }
     }    
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.greenB, this.state.custum]}> 
            </View>
        );
      }
    }  
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        greenB:{
          padding: 5,
          height: 80,
          width: 80,  
          borderRadius:160,    

        },
    })
export default Green;
```

Comment: Can you also post your code that isn't working? You said you tried to change it back to darkgreen, I don't see that in your code above.

Comment: I tried for hours and deleted everything I tried but just because your comment made me try again - it worked now. So thank you lol
What I did was just setting again setstate with settimeout, but  changed the timer so it will match the first one

Answer (score 1):

try this working example acc to your code[expo link](https://snack.expo.io/rJ0NL6alL):

Code is :

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

// You can import from local files
import AssetExample from './components/AssetExample';

// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

class Green extends React.Component {
     constructor(props){
         super(props)
         this.state={
            backgroundColor: 'darkgreen'
         }

     }   

     componentDidMount() {
       setInterval(() => {
         if(this.state.backgroundColor == "darkgreen"){
           this.setState({backgroundColor:'red'})
         } else {
           this.setState({backgroundColor:'darkgreen'})
         }

     },1000)
     }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={[styles.greenB,{backgroundColor:this.state.backgroundColor}]}> 
            </View>
        );
      }
    }  
    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        greenB:{
          padding: 5,
          height: 80,
          width: 80,  
          borderRadius:160,    

        },
    })
export default Green;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
constructor(props) {
     super(props)
     this.state={}
     this.state.custum={
        backgroundColor: 'darkgreen'
     }

     if (this.props.greenFlash){
        this.intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            this.setState(prevState => {
              const bgcolor = (prevState.custum.backgroundColor === 'lightgreen') ? 'darkgreen' : 'lightgreen';
              return {
                custum:{
                    backgroundColor: bgcolor
                 }
                }
            })
        }, 1000);
    }
 }
```

A few things to note:

A) You're saving `this.intervalId` so you can call `clearInterval(this.intervalId)` in your `componentWillUnmount`. Otherwise your interval will keep on calling long after your component has been destroyed.

B) you may want to define your interval in `componentDidMount` instead of the constructor, as that's generally the standard when you're calling `this.setState`, because `this.setState` is not available until `componentDidMount` is called. However, because the first time it will be called is after 1 second, I'm not going to say it's a huge concern. Just standard practice.